Install Builder - Linux - Prevent confirmation message in Terminal
I created an installer using Install Builder.
When installing from Terminal on Debian it shows this message,
Welcome to the Application Setup Wizard.

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Setup is now ready to begin installing Application on your computer.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n]:

What is the XML value that should be added to the Install Builder project file in order to prevent this message and start installing as soon as the user type this command in the Terminal?
./AppInstaller.run


If you're looking for a silent installation, this is done by specifying
the installation mode as unattended.
I quote from
How can I silent install on Mac OS X?

In order to run InstallBuilder based installer in silent mode, you can
specify --mode unattended - such as:
$ Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder.sh --mode unattended

You can also make the unattended mode the default by adding the
following to your project file:
<project>
    <defaultInstallationMode>unattended</defaultInstallationMode>
</project>

This will cause the installer to run in unattended mode by default.
You can also change  to minimalWithDialogs to also
show the progress bar:
<project>
    <defaultInstallationMode>unattended</defaultInstallationMode>     
    <unattendedModeUI>minimalWithDialogs</unattendedModeUI>
</project>

After that, the installer will run in unattended mode by default and
can still be switched to full GUI by running it from command line with
--mode osx or --mode qt depending on if you are using Qt flavor of
InstallBuilder.
However, the user will still have to double-click on the installer -
and due to security issues it is not possible to automate this step
(to avoid automatically running a virus or other unsafe file).

